# Best way of excluding customers with a specific order

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm running a pretty basic query. The issue is I'm trying to get results with all of our customers who never ordered product Y. The problem is, if I use a simple `WHERE ProductColumn <> 'Product Y'`, it doesn't work because almost all of our customers have ordered other products.

Basically, I'm wondering how I could exclude on the customer level (instead of the order level) - if a customer has ordered Product Y, I don't want them showing up in my results at all.

Thanks.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: You need to give us some more info in order to understand the way to query it. At the very list, the structure of your tables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably looking for EXISTS().

If I want to find customers who have placed orders:

```
SELECT c.*
FROM customers c
WHERE EXISTS (
SELECT 1 
FROM orders o
WHERE o.customerid = c.customerID
AND productID = 'Y'
)
```

If I want to find customers who have not placed orders:

```
SELECT c.*
FROM customers c
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
SELECT 1 
FROM orders o
WHERE o.customerid = c.customerID
AND productID = 'Y'
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
select * from customers c
where not exists(select 1 from customers
                 where cutomer_id = c.customer_id
                 and productcolumn = 'product y')
```

This assumes you have 'customer_id' column (or at least some `id` column in your table).

Answer (score 2):

Simple [LEFT JOIN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt8wzxy4.aspx) should work:

```
SELECT c.*
FROM customers c
    LEFT OUTER JOIN orders o
        ON o.customerid = c.customerID
WHERE o.ProductColumn <> 'Product Y'
```